# Strings and Conditionals: a loop return true and false, why the output only return one true as result

Tags: python-3.x

I was writing code for this question: "Write a function called `letter_check`that takes two inputs, `word` and `letter`. This function should return `True` if the word contains the letter and `False` if it does not." The answer it provided is below:

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  for m in word:
   if m == letter:
     return True
  return False
print(letter_check("strawberry","a"))
```

I could not figure out how this work. For example, I thought for the first character in `strawberry`, which is `s`, go into the `for` loop. `s` not equal `a`, exit loop and return `False`. Same result (`False`) for the second character..and goes on.. For the fourth letter `a`, result is `True`. And the rest return `False` again.

so I thought the result of `letter_check("Strawberry","a")` is `false`. (since the last character didn't match "`a`" so the last `return` is `false`) . I don't understand why the result is `true`?

I later learned I could use `in` for this question, but I hope to know why the above coding return `true`

Comment: you may accept the answer that helped you solve your problem :https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 1):

The return statement is the last statement any function would execute. After executing return statement the control moves out of the body of function. So once the condition matches within the loop itself,the function returns true. The control will move out of the loop to the `return false` statement only if it doesn't encounter a `return` statement earlier which would mean the if condition was never true.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you for the explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

Moving on from @Tojrah's already explained reason, You coul duse a boolean flag and an Index var to check for the existance of the char:

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  isFound = False
  Index = None
  for m in word:
     if m == letter:
        isFound = not isFound     # set the flag to true
        Index = word.index(m)     # get the index pos of the letter
  return isFound, Index

print(letter_check("strawberry","a"))
print(letter_check("strawberry","o"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
(True, 3)
(False, None)
```